# Apt-Get Connecting Very Slowly

Tags: networking, 16.04, apt

I'm curious why my `apt-get` seems to be slow. My internet connection is fast and once it connects it downloads very quickly but it seems to hang at

```
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]
```

For a few minutes before connecting, or trying another hit, in which case it hangs again at the next connection. It seems to always work after a little while it just takes a while.

Is there any way to make this faster?

Comment: Have you tried to change download server?

Comment: I went into the settings and ran the wizard for choosing the best mirror. That seems to make the initial connections (such as when doing apt-get update) faster, but then it still seems to always hit a server that takes forever, like for this instance archive.linux.duke.edu worked great but then it started trying dl.google.com which is taking forever.

Comment: What is the version of your Ubuntu? And is it the first time that you see such problem?

Comment: 16.04.01 LTS Xenial, and yes, though it has been a while since I have done anything on this machine